# Console dump of a DCOM configuration for a given GUID?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, dcom

Is there a way to dump the DCOM settings for a given DCOM object on the command line, if the GUID is known? (Maybe using PowerShell)

Comment: I can't recall anything built in but a few uses of `reg query /s ‹path›` over the usual places (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppId\‹GUID›`, ...) shouldn't be too hard to put together. In PSH It would be more work because `Get-ItemProperty` to get the values doesn't have a recursive option, so a combination of `Get-ChildItem -recurse` and `Get-ItemProperty` would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it but it looks like you could use the comadmin class to begin exploring the administrative interfaces ( `$comadmin = new-object -com "comadmin.comadmincatalog"` )

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683573(v=vs.85) for an overview of the comadmin namespace